# Can I update the service on ArcGIS for Server programmatically?

Tags: arcobjects, raster, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, c#

There is Windows Service. This service adds user raster data to the Raster Dataset in sde database.

The Raster Dataset registred on the ArcGis Server. This Raster Dataset also was publishing on ArcGis Server. When the user data has been added to this Raster Dataset, the data is not updated on ArcGis Service.

How update service on the ArcGis Server from my Windows Service? (I know IP address, password, and service name)

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Which ArcGIS Server version you are using? (9.x or 10.x). Please check similar question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27873/arcobjects-arcserver-10-1-how-to-programatically-publish-a-map-service

Comment: thanks, but I had already read this question. I think the most usefull code here is:
  
   `IPropertySet recycle = pConfiguration.RecycleProperties;
    recycle.SetProperty("StartTime", "1:00 AM");
    recycle.SetProperty("Interval", "86400");`

Is it refresh service every 86400 ms? But I'd like refresh service whenever I want.

Comment: We use one arcgis server 10.1 and two arcmap 10.1

Comment: I think you can write 1. ArcPy script to update raster data 2. Refresh ArcSDE though python and then overwrite that map service. I hope it will get an idea for you + check my similar question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61057/overwrite-existing-map-service-in-arcgis-server-10-1-through-arcpy

Answer (score 1):

Here are some troubleshooting steps:

First, check to see if the published map service is cached or not.

- If the map service is cached, then you will need to update the cache in order to see the changes on the ArcGIS service.
- you will then need to create a script that will update the cache whenever new data is added to the raster database.

If the map service is not cached, the newly added raster data should be drawn automatically.  If it is still not showing up:

- open the MXD that was used to publish the map service
- check to make sure the MXD pointing to the correct database
- check to make sure that updated raster data that has been successfully loaded from the script (it might be a scripting error)